# How to speed up import a large csv file to mysql database?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, csv, import

In this moment i have a large csv file which has 11 MB and contains much of data which are inserted to... the end of excel file. So it will be about 1 million rows in 10 columns. Now I'd like to write a c# code which imports this file very faster.

**What i've done?**

First, i have written code which imports all of data from csv file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ControlDataBase
{
    public partial class Import_data_mysql : Form
    {
        public Import_data_mysql()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        New_Tables frm2 = (New_Tables)Application.OpenForms["New_Tables"];

        private DataTable ImportFile()
        {
            DataTable imported_data = new DataTable();

            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Title = "Open csv file";
            ofd.DefaultExt = "*.csv";
            ofd.Filter = "Documents (*.csv)|*.csv";
            ofd.ShowDialog();

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
            string FileName1 = ofd.FileName;
            string excel = fi.FullName;

            using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(excel))
            {
                string header = sr.ReadLine();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Not found or loaded not correct file.");
                    return null;
                }

                string[] header_columns = header.Split(';');
                foreach(string header_column in header_columns)
                {
                    imported_data.Columns.Add(header_column);
                }

                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) continue;

                    string[] fields = line.Split(';');
                    DataRow imported_row = imported_data.NewRow();

                    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        imported_row[i] = fields[i];
                    }

                    imported_data.Rows.Add(imported_row);
                }
            }
            return imported_data;
        }
```

Second, i can insert into mysql database to "order_status" table:

```
 private void save_status_to_database(DataTable imported_data)
        {
            string connect = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;CharSet=utf8mb4";
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connect))
            {
                conn.Open();
                foreach (DataRow importRow in importowane_dane.Rows)
                {
                    string query5 = @INSERT IGNORE INTO try1.order_status(ID_WORKER, ID_ORDER, ID_MODULE, ID_PROJECT,
                    AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE) SELECT workers.ID_WORKER, orders.ID_ORDER, module.ID_MODULE,
                    projects.ID, @AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, @BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE FROM try1.workers INNER JOIN try1.orders 
                    INNER JOIN try1.modules INNER JOIN try1.projects WHERE workers.FNAME = @FNAME AND workers.LNAME = @LNAME
                    AND workers.ID_WORKER = @ID_WORKER AND orders.DESC_ORDER = @DESC_ORDER 
                    AND orders.ORDER_NUMBER = @ORDER_NUMBER AND modules.NAME = @MODULES_NAME 
                    AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME"

                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query5, conn);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_WORKER", importRow["ID_WORKER"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", importRow["FNAME"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", importRow["LNAME"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESC_ORDER", importRow["DESC_ORDER"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDER_NUMBER", importRow["ORDER_NUMBER"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODULES_NAME", importRow["NAME"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_NAME", importRow["PROJECT_NAME"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS", importRow["AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", importRow["BEGIN_DATE"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", importRow["END_DATE"]);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Imported to database.");
        }
```

But when I insert 11 MB of large file it imports much time that will be about 10 minutes. And in half time of way while compiling this code process memory has about... 5 GB!

Now I'm wondering that how can i speed importing data from large csv file. `MysqlBulkLoader` will be enough? Maybe should rewrite importing code in other way? Any ideas? Thx for any help.

**What I've tried?**

I've tried by running in x64 mode and adding `<runtime> <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" /> </runtime>` in App.config. But it hasn't helped yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think ImportFile function is good, dont should be a problem.
Extra time was on SQLQuery and foreach. You should use some update batch function, instead one query one row.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name
    (a,b,c)
VALUES
    (1,2,3),
    (4,5,6),
    (7,8,9);
```

1.Build imported_data from file

2.Build Sql query from imported_data

3.Run Query

Maybe you can do 1 and 2 on same time. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

### Using Load Data query to import csv files

Step1: In blank query editor check variable by:
 Show variables like "local_infile";
check if it is ON or not. if not then
 Set global local_infile = 1;

Now close query and workbench and open it again.

Step2: [Right click to connection when you open workbench 8.0 and go to edit connection and then Advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXsiH.png)

Step 3: [in others section write below code: OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m17ui.png)

Step4: Now we can write query to load local file.

-- to upload big csv files in database while copying path, make sure it has forward slash
-- The path that contains program data is specified directory where we need to paste the csv file first and then use this code

Load data local infile 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/CovidDeath.csv'
into table project1.coviddeath
Fields terminated by ','
-- ignoring 1st row as it contains headers
Ignore 1 rows;

Note: "--" refers to comments and documentations. Please adjust query if it has not been copied properly.